# Flutter Web Application Not Loading In Mobile Browser

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have created a mobile application for my business using Flutter and it is [published in PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bambusakrafty) which is working fine.

Later I have converted the application to web-friendly and built it using Flutter Web and hosted it using Firebase Hosting. You can see the website here: https://youmenotes.com/immadekada/bambusa/#/

Now the problem which I am trying to resolve is, the website is loading as per expectation in desktop browsers, but if I try to open this URL using mobile phone browsers, it is stuck in a white screen. No clue on how to resolve it.

Please give me some light on the issue if anyone faced the same.

Thanks!

---

Note: I have another Flutter Web app (a demo app) that is hosted using the same way, and it is working perfectly alright on both PC and mobile browsers. The URL is this: https://youmenotes.com/immadekada/bambusa/game1/#/

Comment: Have you checked your server logs? Like did you find any errors? Because it's weird how it's working on the desktop version of chrome but not in mobile view.

Answer (score 6):

This was happened to me-

step 1: check if it is running fine on local
for that run following command

> `flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8080 --web-hostname 0.0.0.0`
> and check form your mobile which is same network as your pc by
> entering url `<pc's ip address:8080/>`

step 2: build web with canvaskit render which is more suitable for mobile brower,

> command: `flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release` and
> release it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, for spending your time to find a solution for the issue. Here I have found the solution.

It was a simple coding issue that caused the incorrect behavior in mobile browsers!

There were some mobile-only features in my application and which I handled using the following method:

```
bool isMobile() {
  if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS ||
          defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

So it was working as expected when running from mobile as a mobile application, and running in a computer as a web application. But when it comes to running it from a Mobile device as a web application, the method returns `true` since the platform is Android/iOS. And that caused my business logic to misbehave.

I updated the if condition with a proper checking for the web by adding `kIsWeb`, and the method started to return values properly.

Now the URL is loading correctly in both web and mobile browsers.
https://youmenotes.com/immadekada/bambusa/#/

Thanks, for your time.

---

**Update:**

### How did I identify the issue?

Using [Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) on mobile devices.
[image: You can navigate to this page on chrome by using the URL chrome://inspect/#devices]
You can navigate to this page on chrome by using the URL `chrome://inspect/#devices`

Thanks,
Midhun.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, Flutter web often reports the platform as Android or iOS when running in a mobile browser to provide a mobile-like experience.

```
bool get isMobile =>
    defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android ||
    defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS;
```

If you run this code in a Flutter web application and access it from a mobile browser, the isMobile getter is likely to return true.

so must ensure `kIsWeb == false`.

```
bool get isMobile =>
    (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android ||
        defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) &&
    kIsWeb == false;
```